# Excel: Set comboboxes 3-8 .visible to false if ComboBox 1 is empty

Tags: combobox, userform, shortcut

I have a UserForm with ComboBoxes 1-8 that each pick up text in designated cells in the ws upon UserForm_Activate. I have set ComboBoxes 2-8 to `.Visible=False` if ComboBox1.Value = "".

Is there a way to use an abbreviated code to set `.Visible=False` for each ComboBox without listing each one separately? I have added below what I'm using now, but I create forms like this often and would rather use a "Dim i as Integer / For i =" type thing instead that I could just copy and paste where needed. Thank you in advance!

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
ComboBox2.Visible = False
ComboBox3.Visible = False
ComboBox4.Visible = False
ComboBox5.Visible = False
ComboBox6.Visible = False
ComboBox7.Visible = False
ComboBox8.Visible = False
```

Comment: Posted an answer; btw it makes no difference to use Long instead of Integer (especially using row or column indices you are on the safe side :) @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Indirect referencing of controls**

Use indirect referencing via `Controls()` and try

```
Dim i As Long, current As Long
current = 1             ' << change to the combobox to be excepted
For i = 1 to 8          ' loop through all comboboxes
    Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Visible = False
Next i
Me.Controls("ComboBox" & current).Visible = True
```

Comment: Thank you - it works perfectly! Is there any way to change this to where only only certain  CBs are affected? Say, every other one, or every third one, etc?

Comment: You are welcome, @LorenScholes. - Regarding your question: of course you can, depends on your naming convention e.g. starting from CB1, CB4, CB7, ... to CBn. In this case you could a) either add a `For i = 1 to 8 Step 3` condition to your loop or b) execute a check within the `For`-`Next`  loop, e.g. via `If (i - 1) Mod 3 = 0 Then` ... `End If`; just play around to test :-)